# Add variable to purchasable variant to modify price?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to somehow (plugin or otherwise) modify the price of a lineItem/variant based on variables like material or any other additional modifier (basically affecting the same stock of items).

For example:
Pillow (with variants being color)
— Stuffing material
— Print yes/no

The pillow base product itself is a finite number of items for each color, but the stuffing isn't fixed in that sense, effectively being infinite in terms of stock.

Would it be possible to create separate products and use the Multi Add plugin for this, rather than doing some form of (preferably simpler) custom approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Multi Add will be the simplest approach here - it really won't be hard with that, and Luke repeated recently that multi-add will become core, so apart from some possible minor template modification later, it seems a sensible way to build this - and will be simpler (going forward as  well) than writing a new plugin for it, where you'll have to take a lot more care with your extra logic for shipping/tax etc.  Multi add just adds multiple products, but leverages core ine very other way, so it's a very robust solution.